# Get current currency symbol

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

`<?php echo $currency_symbol.$value ?>`

I want that Yii automatically change `$currency_symbol` from `€` to `$`. For example, in function of the current Locale Id (Language). So, if the current user has a Locale Id like `it_it`, the currency code will be `EUR` and the symbol `€`. In case of a Locale Id like `en_us`, the currency code will be `USD` and the symbol `$`.

Is it possible?

I tried to do it but the only ways are:

`Yii::app()->getNumberFormatter()->formatCurrency('100','EUR');`
`CLocale::getInstance($language)->getCurrencySymbol('EUR');`

In each situation I'm forced to set `EUR` manually. I don't want to do it, because if I change the language Yii will not automatically 'translate' the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The [localeconv](https://www.php.net/localeconv) function returns an array of values including the currency symbol of the currently set local.

So you could do something like

```
$locale = localeconv();
$currency_symbol = $locale['currency_symbol']
```

You will need to use [setLocale()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) manually whenever you want to change the locale/currency but this should work for translating based on the user's locale.